# Indexing in a crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi i am new to asp.net programing language.  I want to have an index page in my crystal report can somebody provide me with an example how to create an index page in a crystal report.

I will really apreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you need a main page from where you want to navigate to other pages. If I am right, then you can crate groups in the crystal reports. Now from those group headers you can navigate to other parts(details) of the report.

I hope this helps.